# Align the system of equations

Tags: align, cases

Consider:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{llr}
\begin{rcases*}
    $\lim\limits_{x\to2^+}f(x)&=\lim\limits_{x\to2^+}\sqrt{5x-1}&=3$\\
    $\lim\limits_{x\to2^-}f(x)&=\lim\limits_{x\to2^-}(3x^2-4x-1)&=3$\\
    $f(2)&=\sqrt{5\cdot2-1}&=3$
\end{rcases*}\Leftrightarrow \displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to2^-}f(x)=f(2)=\lim\limits_{x\to2^+}f(x)
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

I was getting:

[image]

But I want the result like this:

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}  
    \[\def\arraystretch{2}\arraycolsep=1.6pt
    \left.\begin{array}{llr}
        \lim\limits_{x\to2^+}f(x) &= \lim\limits_{x\to2^+}\sqrt{5x-1} &= 3\\
        \lim\limits_{x\to2^-}f(x) &= \lim\limits_{x\to2^-}(3x^2-4x-1) &= 3\\
        f(2)                     &= \sqrt{5\cdot2-1}                  &=3
    \end{array}\right\}
    \Leftrightarrow \displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to2^-}f(x)=f(2)=\lim\limits_{x\to2^+}f(x)
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks sir, it was solve my problem.

Comment: Your use of an `array` environment induces a strong degree of asymmetry around the `=` symbols inside the `array`. Can you think of a method places the `=` symbols more symmetrically?

Comment: I still haven't found a suitable way to solve it. How do you think we can do it in an array 
 environment?

Comment: i was try put \ after &= to create more distance, it become &=\ \lim\limits_{.... but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: use `\def\arraystretch{2}\arraycolsep=2pt`

Answer (score 11):

I have three proposals, none of which uses `cases` or variants, which are not suited for the job.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}  

\[
\left.
\begin{alignedat}{2}
  \lim_{x\to2^+}f(x) &= \lim_{x\to2^+}\sqrt{5x-1}&&=3\\
  \lim_{x\to2^-}f(x) &= \lim_{x\to2^-}(3x^2-4x-1)&&=3\\
  f(2)&=\sqrt{5\cdot2-1}&&=3
\end{alignedat}
\right\}\Leftrightarrow \lim_{x\to2^-}f(x)=f(2)=\lim_{x\to2^+}f(x)
\]

\[
\left.
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\displaystyle}l}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\displaystyle{}}l}
\begin{array}{ABB}
  \lim_{x\to2^+}f(x) &= \lim_{x\to2^+}\sqrt{5x-1}&=3\\
  \lim_{x\to2^-}f(x) &= \lim_{x\to2^-}(3x^2-4x-1)&=3\\
  f(2)&=\sqrt{5\cdot2-1}&=3
\end{array}
\right\}\Leftrightarrow \lim_{x\to2^-}f(x)=f(2)=\lim_{x\to2^+}f(x)
\]

\[
\left.
\begin{aligned}
&\! \lim_{x\to2^+}f(x) = \lim_{x\to2^+}\sqrt{5x-1}=3 \\
&\! \lim_{x\to2^-}f(x) = \lim_{x\to2^-}(3x^2-4x-1)=3 \\
&   f(2)=\sqrt{5\cdot2-1}=3
\end{aligned}
\right\}\lim_{x\to2^-}f(x)=f(2)=\lim_{x\to2^+}f(x)
\]

\end{document}
```

I'd much prefer the last one: the three parts left to the brace are not really connected to one another and aligning the equals signs is not needed and makes for bad blanks. The `\Leftrightarrow` symbol is mathematically wrong.

[image]

Comment: can you explain to me the purpose of ```\!``` you use in the last one?

Comment: @manh3 For good reasons, the material after the odd-numbered `&` in `aligned` and similar environments is implicitly preceded by `{}`, to get the spacing right, as usually a relation symbol follows. When (ab)using `aligned` for global left alignment, a math operator such as `\lim` would be preceded by a thin space and `\!` cancels it.

Comment: maybe because my english is not good i still don't understand it well. I've tried removing ```\!``` at the command line but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Can you give an example?

Comment: @manh3 Look closely. The `x` in the limit will be slightly to the right of the “f” in the bottom line.

Comment: oh right, I was see it. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You're not making good use of the `rcases*` machinery; I would ditch it in favor a simple `\left. ... \right\}` wrapper. To format the material to left of the tall curly brace, I suggest you employ an `alignedat{3}` environment. This will allow you to get rid of all `\displaystyle` and `\limits` directives.

Optionally, you could use `\mathclap` directives to get rid of the whitespace around the `\lim` terms. The solutions without and with the `\mathclap` idea are shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{%%amsmath, %% amsmath is loaded automatically by mathtools
            amssymb}
%%\usepackage{amsfonts} %% amsfonts is loaded automatically by amssymb
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathclap macro
\begin{document}  

\noindent
Basic solution:
\[
\left.
\begin{alignedat}{3}
    &\lim_{x\to2^+}f(x)&&=\lim_{x\to2^+}\sqrt{5x-1}&&=3\\
    &\lim_{x\to2^-}f(x)&&=\lim_{x\to2^-}(3x^2-4x-1)&&=3\\
    &f(2)              &&=\sqrt{5\cdot2-1}         &&=3
\end{alignedat}
\,\right\}
\Leftrightarrow  \lim_{x\to2^-}f(x)=f(2)=\lim_{x\to2^+}f(x)
\]


\bigskip\noindent
With \verb+\mathclap+:
\[
\left.
\begin{alignedat}{3}
    &\lim_{\mathclap{x\to2^+}}f(x)&&=\lim_{\mathclap{x\to2^+}}\sqrt{5x-1}&&=3\\
    &\lim_{\mathclap{x\to2^-}}f(x)&&=\lim_{\mathclap{x\to2^-}}(3x^2-4x-1)&&=3\\
    &f(2)                         &&=\sqrt{5\cdot2-1}                    &&=3
\end{alignedat}
\,\right\}
\Leftrightarrow  \lim_{\mathclap{x\to2^-}}f(x)=f(2)=\lim_{\mathclap{x\to2^+}}f(x)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your advice. I will pay attention to this issue.